# block reference in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I have a swift NSURLConnection block.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    self.updateDataToPlace(jsonResult)                  
})
```

`Question`: Is it safe to use `self.updateDataToPlace(jsonResult)` as above?

In objective-C I'd usually make a weak reference of self for something like this.

`__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? Where is the self.myMethod() statement?

Comment: A few tips on writing swift: (1) You can leave out the type declaration in a closure, Swift knows what type they are. Only if you want to cast them, do you need it. (2) `var`s that you only need to write to once are better declared as `let`. (3) You don't need to explicitly state the type (`: NSDictionary`) when the compiler knows what type it is (`as NSDictionary`). (4) When the compiler knows what type to expect, you can use the syntactic sugar `.MutableContainers` instead of `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers` (but Xcode doesn't autocomplete this yet...)

Comment: @Jawwad Please take a look now, I updated the questions. Forgive me for unclear language earlier. Perils of working late hours.

Comment: @vrwim I understand, I typecasted it only when compiler showed me an error when I didn't typecaste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `self` does not have a reference to the block so you would not need to make `self` weak. But if you did, you would use capture lists as @Stripes mentioned. `self` would also become an optional in this case.

So something like this:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: nil) { [weak self] response, data, error in
    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    self?.updateDataToPlace(jsonResult)
}
```

(I've updated your code slightly to be more concise and use trailing closure syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Before the (response: but after the { you want a capture list.

For exactly what you had in ObjC use

```
[weak self]
```

Beware if you ever make a variable weak it is slower to dealloc (plus all the more commonly known pitfalls).

You can also try

```
[unowned self]
```

That could be faster, but only use it if you know that the block can't outlive the object otherwise you get a mess to debug.

For more details look up   [capture list on Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Comment: link here: [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Comment: @Stripes This approach didn't work, and I'm still working on Capture lists.

Comment: I'll cut and paste an example when I get to a real computer